# Multiple questions on same dialog

Tags: dpkg, debconf

How do I setup the postinst script and template to have multiple questions on same dialog and get their return values in different `$RET`

My current code:

## template

```
Template: foo/like_debian
Type: boolean                            
Description: Do you like Debian?
 We'd like to know if you like the Debian GNU/Linux system

Template: foo/like_debian2
Type: boolean                            
Description: Do you really like Debian?
 We'd like to know if you really like the Debian GNU/Linux system
```

## postinst

```
# Do you like debian?
db_input medium foo/like_debian || true
db_go
db_get foo/like_debian
echo $RET

# Do you really like debian?
db_input medium foo/like_debian2 || true
db_go
db_get foo/like_debian2
echo $RET
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you asked is, how can I ask two questions and get two answers? Something like this should do the trick:

```
db_input medium foo/like_debian || true
[...]
ANSWER1=$RET
db_input medium foo/like_debian2 || true
[...]
ANSWER2=$RET
echo $ANSWER1,$ANSWER2
```

The key thing here is that your post/pre inst & rm scripts are using $RET as the input, so you need to save that return value as a new variable. I'd recommending reading this article if you want to know more about this: https://www.leaseweb.com/labs/2013/06/creating-custom-debian-packages/

## Update

I don't know why I missed what you were asking before but to get multiple questions on the same screen at the same time you'd use beginblock and endblock:

```
db_beginblock
db_input medium foo/like_debian || true
db_input medium foo/like_debian2 || true
db_endblock
db_go
```

This should do the trick. Also, just FYI your db_get commands are only necessary if you want to get the previous value and since you're default is true and this is a postinst script they're probably not necessary in your example. Also keep in mind that not all interfaces support this beginblock/endblock so depending on how you're testing this you may or may not see it. For more info see:
http://www.fifi.org/doc/debconf-doc/tutorial.html#AEN217

Comment: This makes you ask two questions on two different dialogs/pages after each other: The thing is I want both the question on the same dialog/page.

Comment: Oh sure, that'd be beginblock and endblock tags

Comment: Though I could not get it working really. Thanks for the pointer. You deserve the bounty!